# Is it possible to predict if a single variable function of form y= f(x) can have a point with zero slope ??

Tags: derivatives

Is it possible to predict if a single variable function of form y= f(x) can have a point with zero slope without plotting an X-Y graph of the function??

Also if a function of form y=f(x) have points with zero slopes, is it possible to predict if one of these points represent the maximum of that function, without plotting an X-Y graph of the function ??

Comment: If it is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=f(b)$ then it will have points with zero slope on $(a,b)$ by the [Mean Value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), and at least one of them will be a min or a max.

Comment: If the function is differentiable, yes; find the derivative and solve $f’(x)=0$; then use the first derivative test to check if they are extremes.